# WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl cannot be cast to WeblogicWebAppBean

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I'm working on Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0, and my web application is already deployed and Active.
But all the URLs in the web app throws me 404.

Also it has not published any testing URLs in the Admin console too.

When I switched to Configurations tab (Deployments>AppName>Configuration) I can see an exception there in that tab.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl cannot be cast to weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicWebAppBean
```

Searched all the files within my application, but could not find a single reference to above classes.

Can somone please help me on this?

Comment: When you try to hit one of the URLs in your app, what does the server log file show? If I had to guess, there are also errors when you deploy your application. Uninstall and reinstall your app with the admin console and look in the log for errors